# Xcode 10 Signing Error: Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I've recently upgraded to Xcode 10.2.1 - clients have updated their devices to iOS 12.2 which caused features of mobile app to stop working (camera / qr scanner). So rebuilt my app in new Xcode (it's an ionic app). I can build and run in the simulator via Xcode but can't archive for distribution. Looks like a code signing error which I can't get around.

Have already tried re-assigning profiles, cleaning build, deleting derived data.

**Log output**

```
probing signature of /Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign E53B3573B6BABE35C4A71D789E5E5058D1895105 --verbose /Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: This is an issue with your libswiftsimd.dylib framework. are you using two xcode in your system? if yes then check your toolchain version under xcode -> preferance -> toolchain

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Menu - File -> Project Settings

Change Build System - to Legacy Build System and try

Let me know if it works

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried that already, sorry should have mentioned that. One thing I have noticed as I get a slightly different error if I keep cleaning the build and re-running the archive task. I've done this about 5 or 6 times and I got different files reportedly throwing the error.. last one was "libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all". Very bizarre.

Comment: Edit: If I archive using Legacy Build System, I get the following:

Codesigning /Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bootcamp_Admin-ajntpyeonsdorvblemqwhyetkmpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Bootcamp Admin/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Bootcamp Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
.....
 Admin.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: errSecInternalComponent
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
}

Comment: try doing pod install once... remember no pod update. Also check the certificates.